# How to create wordpress new user from html form?

Tags: wordpress

This is my first attemp to create a wordpress plugin.
The form part works, and an email is sent to site admin.
But the new wordpress user isnt created.

Sorry if this is obvoious, but I havent coded before and am trying to marry up bits of code.

I assume the problem is that the form isnt in a way that the user creation component can understand.

```
function html_form_code() {
echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your Name (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["username"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["username"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="email" name="email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Subject (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="finance-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9  ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["finance-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["finance-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your Message (required) <br/>';
echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="finance-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["finance-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["finance-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Hi speedy, first off I suggest just get the action to fire when and ONLY when you want.  Maybe just issue a debug to the error_log so yu can see when it is firing. Admin_init fires EVERY time an access is made to a wp admin page. NOt a good choice for inserting a user.  See  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init

Comment: While testing consider having the "insert user code" to be triggered from a button in html, so you can then dump the response.  I'd dump what is being returned - there maybe info there telling you what is wrong.  
I'd also specify as little fields as you can get away with in the beginning.  WP will probably fill in the blanks.

Once you have both aspects working, then you can put them together.  Start with very small steps.

Comment: Where is the form processing code/function?

Comment: function html_form_code() {
 echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
 echo '<p>';
 echo '<p>';
 echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
 echo '<input type="email" name="email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '<p>';
 echo '<p><input type="submit" name="finance-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
 echo '</form>';
}